# How to bind a std::function to JavaScript V8?

Tags: javascript, c++, binding, v8, std-function

I just started using [JavaScript V8](https://developers.google.com/v8/) and compiled a basic example from the [Embedder's Guide](https://developers.google.com/v8/embed). Now I want to bind C++ functions to the JavaScript context.

For now I only have a more or less blank class which should handle binding later on.

```
class Manager
{
public:
    Manager()
    {
        context = Context::New();
    }
    void Bind(string Name, function<Handle<Value>(const Arguments&)> Function)
    {
        // bind the function to the given context
    }
private:
    Persistent<Context> context;
};
```

How can I bind a `std::function` object to the JavaScript V8 context?

Comment: I used to bind functions in my engine with something like `void BindExample(v8::Handle<v8::ObjectTemplate> engine) { engine->Set(v8::String::New("FunctionInJS"), v8::FunctionTemplate::New(FunctionInCPP)); }`. Does this help somehow?

Comment: That helps me but what exactly is the handle called engine in your example? But actually the main issue is about passing the `std::function` as a parameter.

Comment: Please refer to my full example in the answer and my suggestions on what to try about `std::function`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter type `InvocationCallback` which is requested by the `Set` function is a simple typedef.

```
typedef Handle<Value> (*InvocationCallback)(Arguments const &);
```

Therefore I had to convert the `std::function` to a raw function pointer.

```
void Register(string Name, function<Handle<Value>(Arguments const &)> Function)
{
    InvocationCallback* function = Function.target<InvocationCallback>();
    globals->Set(String::New(Name.c_str()), FunctionTemplate::New(*function));
}
```

Comment: I think you should unaccept this answer because, as you found out in another question, this doesn't work for the general case.

Comment: @minexew Can you provide a link to the other question you're referring to, please?

Answer (score 3):

What I used in my engine was a rather complicated approach but the very first I came up with. (Sadly I moved from V8 to LLVM such that I haven't been optimizing this.)

```
void ExposeFunctions(v8::Handle<v8::ObjectTemplate> engine) {
    /* ... */
    engine->Set(v8::String::New("Exit"), v8::FunctionTemplate::New(NativeExit));
    engine->Set(v8::String::New("Log"), v8::FunctionTemplate::New(NativeLog));
    /* ... */
}

int SpawnEngine() {
    v8::Locker locker;
    v8::HandleScope handleScope;
    v8::TryCatch exceptionManager;
    v8::Handle<v8::ObjectTemplate> global = v8::ObjectTemplate::New();
    ExposeFunctions(global);
    v8::Persistent<v8::Context> context = v8::Context::New(nullptr, global);
    v8::Context::Scope scope(context);
    /* ... */
    context.Dispose();
    return 0;
}
```

This should give you at least a possible solution to bind native functions to the interpreter which you could rework for your needs.

Considering your problem using a function object one could try (just guessing here) to pass it directly like I did with named functions, or nest it in a lambda expression passed to `v8::FunctionTemplate::New`. But its quite a while since I worked with this.